# Localhost won't load

Tags: mysql, wordpress, localhost

I had to reset my router and modem, after a 3 hour task of getting those working properly again I can connect to the internet.

I had WordPress running locally on MAMP and the IP address I'd connect to was `http://192.168.1.141:8888`, now I can't access this address at all locally, the page never properly loads. `http://localhost:8888/MAMP/` does load, I can access phpMyAdmin, start page etc.

However `localhost:8888` sort of 'half' loads? I can see the title of the site I have running locally in the browser tab and at the bottom it says 'connecting to `http://192.168.1.141:8888`' but it never loads properly.

Restarted MAMP, cleared browser cache, restarted computer etc, nothing fixes it.

Comment: Does the machine running the website have a static IP address? It might have changed when you reset your router. Check your machine's local IP to see if it has changed.

Comment: Yeah good point, the machine running it changed to 92.239.151.12

Answer (score 2):

While `192.168.1.141` is the address you used to connect to, after resetting your router and modem, depending on how your router assigns IP addresses (statically or dynamically), your IP address may have changed.

How to check your ip address on Windows:

- Click start menu
- type in `cmd.exe`
- type `ipconfig` into the terminal
- your ip address should be listed in the results

@gilsho: ifconfig is the *nix command, MAMP I think stands for Microsoft / Apache / Mysql / PHP.

**Correction: @gilsho: you are right. MAMP is Mac, so you would use ifconfig.**
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAMP

Once you confirm your ip address, we can continue to help you.

Edit: To make things easier for you, I would go into your router (usually 10.0.0.1 or 192.168.0.1) and set up your ip address to a static one (they usually make it easy for you; your mac address can be found in the `ipconfig` results, just assign the mac address to an ip address in the range it assigns you. That way, the router will always give you the same ip regardless of whether it is restarted or not.). This will not mean you can access your webpage outside of your router network though.

Edit #2:

Try using a simple index.html (maybe your apache comes with one) that you can try loading. Perhaps it is your webpage that bricks something while loading. In any case, it's best to simplify the problem. If you can load a simple html "hello world" page, then it's likely a problem with your code.

Edit #3:

Is your webpage using any additional technologies? You have PHP, Python, Ajax/jQuery, etc. etc. If one of these components or plugins is missing or not configured, you may also see problems such as loading issues, 405/500 errors, etc.

Comment: Between the site loading and not loading, did anything happen? Did you **just** reset your router, or did you move any code/files to a new instance of MAMP? Any additional details you can give us?

Comment: And I **know** this may sound condescending, but is your local machine plugged into the router properly? your ip address does not sound like a commonly given ip address...

Comment: Well I'm definitely connected to my router by virtue of the fact I'm using it's wifi to connect to the internet. I don't know it's local IP though so I can't connect to it... :/ Tried a network scan and it's only giving me what looks like an external IP

Comment: Is it feasible to use a wire to connect in?

Answer (score 1):

Routers typically use DHCP to hand out local IP address to host machines. I suspect that when you restarted your router your machine received a different IP address. In order to find your new IP address, run:

```
ifconfig
```

from the command line. The output should look something like this:

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether c9:a4:51:43:5b:1b 
inet6 fe80::bae8:56ff:ae23:5c1a%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
inet6 2601:9:400:1185:bae8:56ff:fe43:5b1a prefixlen 64 autoconf 
inet6 2601:9:400:1185:fdcd:395b:4671:7cbf prefixlen 64 autoconf temporary 
inet 192.168.1.113 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
media: autoselect
status: active
```

search for the **inet** field, that's your current local IP address.

Comment: How do you know that OP is running Linux?

Comment: What OS are you using? Linux and Mac OSX have command lines built in that you can use.

Comment: Yup, command line already told me my new IP is 92.239.151.12 as per AlGavilian's comment, still that page doesn't load when I append :8888 (apache port) to the end.

Comment: hmm... 92.239.151.12 doesn't seem like a private IP address. Perhaps you have multiple interfaces. Do you see other entries for "inet" in the output?

Comment: inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is what you get when you type 'localhost'. It certainly isn't that one. One option is to log in to your router and see which IP address are connected to it. Yet another option is to use a tool such as 'nmap' to search your local network and see which hosts are connected to your network.

Answer (score 0):

Ok well that took FOREVER to fix, but after I managed to reset my router and set all that up again I decided to use manual DHCP and just changed it back to my old local IP.

God, working with any equipment you get from an ISP is a nightmare.